# Photoshop pattern gradients

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, patterns

Is there any way to have two patterns instead of two colors for a gradient?

I am trying to make a terrain where by the two types of ground textures blend into each other with a gradient, which makes me wonder if patterns can be used in gradients instead of colors.

If not - what would be the simpler alternative to create the same idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by using a layer mask on one of the pattern layers.

1. Make 2 layers, one with each pattern.

[image: Layers]

2. On the top layer, add a **layer mask**([image: Layer mask])
3. On the layer mask, you can then draw a gradient using black and white or even draw with other tools. With layer masks, values in a range of black to white represent the transparency of a pixel, where black is transparent and white is solid.

[image: Result]